# Why [[nodiscard]] doesn't work with a reference?

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, language-lawyer, nodiscard

It looks like the attribute `[[nodiscard]]` doesn't work when the function returns a reference.

This code gives the expected warning:

```
int a;

[[nodiscard]] int get()
{
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    get();
}
```

However, this code compiles without any complains even with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`:

```
int a;

[[nodiscard]] int& get()
{
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    get();
}
```

The only difference between the two is that the function returns a reference in the second test.

The version of my compiler is `g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0`.

Is this a correct behavior or a bug in the compiler?
If this is deliberate, what is the reason for that?

Comment: Looks to be a bug.  gcc 8.1 rejects the code: https://wandbox.org/permlink/FsWgMoQxPszXa75x

Comment: For these kinds of questions, my first comment is always "Does it reproduce using the most current version of ____?"

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/BdRZToYWdkhayeeY